# Problems inserting "|" instead of " " when space key is pressed

Tags: c#

I have a `TextBox` control. After pressing space, I want, instead of whitespace, to put `"|"`. This is my code:

```
void TextBox1KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("|");
    }
}
```

Problem is it doesn't write only `"|"`, but `"| "`: After the pipe char, it puts a space and the cursor moves after that space. I tried to use this method:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, (textBox1.TextLength - 1));
```

but it doesn't work because it deletes `"|"` instead of the space.

And another question is: I want to disable inserting " " when Space is pressed when textbox is empty. When u want to press space while textbox is empty, nothing happens, textbox will stay empty and cursor stay at the begining of textbox

i try this

> void TextBox1KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>   {
>
> if (textBox1.Text.Length==0 && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space) {
>
> ```
>           textBox1.Text=string.Empty;
>
>   }
> ```
>
> }

It doesnt work cause same reason like my previous question. That event is handled after " " is already added so textbox is not empty

PS: sorry for my english and thanks to whoever edit my post and fix my grammatical and spellig errors

Comment: Try to use `onKeyRelease`

Comment: This question does not deserve down votes, in my modest opinion.

Comment: @nbro: I agree, most developer learn with try-and-error the correct sequence of events of UI components.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of KeyPress handle your requirement in the KeyDown event

```
void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && e.Modifiers ==  Keys.None)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        textBox1.AppendText("|");
    }
}
```

As noted below from DrewMcGowen, this will add always the pipe at the end of the textbox text. If you move the cursor somewhere inside the current text the behavior of this approach is confusing and probably incorrect. 
This code instead tries to place the pipe exactly where the cursor is

```
void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && e.Modifiers ==  Keys.None)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        int pos = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, pos) + "|" + textBox1.Text.Substring(pos);
        textBox1.SelectionStart = pos + 1;   
    }
}
```

Notice also that a check on the value of the [Modifiers property of the KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter is mandatory. For example ALT+SPACE should activate the System Menu and not change your textbox in any way (see comment below from [Mr HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)). Checking for `Keys.None` will avoid this logic also for CTRL and SHIFT modifiers, if you want these modifiers to be accounted for you need to change that check.

Comment: Argh, I was just about to post this! One thing though is that this'll always put the pipe at the end of the text instead of at the cursor.

Comment: Using KeyDown for this is almost never not a mistake.  Relying on a predictable keyboard layout is hazardous the further East your code travels, a failure mode in this code anywhere in the world is that Alt+Space is supposed to bring up the system menu, not add a |

Comment: @HansPassant guess you are right :-)  Added a bit of mitigation with a check on Modifiers

Answer (score 3):

The `OnKeyPress` event is fired **before** the space is added.

The workflow is thus:

1. You press down `[Space]`;
2. The event is fired adding `|` to the content; and
3. The space event itself is handled adding a space to the content.

You need to use `KeyRelease` or `KeyUp`...

Comment: I don't even need to know this yet but it gives a good insight into what I'll have to think about +1

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says:

> **Use the KeyChar property** to sample keystrokes at run time and **to modify keystrokes** under special run-time circumstances. For example, you can use KeyChar to disable non-numeric keypresses when the user enters a ZIP code, change all alphabetical keypresses to uppercase in a data entry field, or monitor the keyboard or other key input device for specific key combinations.

So all you need is

```
if (e.KeyChar == ' ')
{
    e.KeyChar = '|';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `e.Handled = true;` to suppress the space.

Monkeying with the user input is rather unwise.  It is very disorienting and plain just doesn't work in some cases.  Obvious failure modes are the user typing Ctrl+V or using right-click + Paste to insert text.  Do this correctly with the Validating event:

```
    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(' ', '|');
    }
```

With high odds that you want to further improve this code by checking for two || next to each other or a leading or trailing |.  You can set e.Cancel = true when you're unhappy, use ErrorProvider to give the user hints.